# How to install StackApplet on Fedora 16?

Tags: fedora, kde, software-installation

Is possible to install the StackApplet on my Fedora 16 (under KDE) ?

Comment: [Its `stackapps.com` site has an `.rpm` package for *RedHat-based* distributions](http://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-bringing-stack-exchange-notifications-to-your-desktop-1-6-alpha-f), like Fedora.  Have you tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the RPM [here](https://launchpad.net/stackapplet).

I successfully installed the noarch RPM on my FC16 KDE environment.

`sudo yum localinstall /path/to/stackapplet-1.5-2.noarch.rpm`

or

`sudo rpm -Uvh "https://launchpad.net/stackapplet/1.5/1.5/+download/stackapplet-1.5-2.noarch.rpm"`

The applet shows up in the system widget on my panel.

Comment: Emmm, with the last command, how can I install my stackapplet? Is it only to download?

Comment: The `rpm` command will download and install. You need to run with `sudo` or as root. I've added quotes around the URL. My fault. The `yum` command assumes you have already downloaded the RPM.

Comment: Thank you! On other hand, if the applet was updated, I can only update my own applet or I must download again?

Comment: You can run the command `rpm -Uvh "http://launchpad.net/stackapplet/some-new-version.rpm"` and it will upgrade your currently installed RPM.

Comment: And for example, exist a form to add to my Fedora repositories for only when I execute yum update, obtain the newest version?

Comment: Ah, now that's a different question. The RPM will have to exist in a `yum` enabled package repository. That repository will have to be defined on your system. If you would like more information, I would suggest searching U&L for `yum` and then optionally asking a new question.